# how to select the second last item from unordered list with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, html-lists

I am working on a selenium project. The website I want to scrape from has an `unordered list` with class name `pagination`. this is how the `unordered list` code looks

```
<ul class="pagination">
    <li class="a-disabled">←<span class="a-letter-space"></span><span class="a-letter-space"></span>Previous</li>    
    <li class="a-selected"><a href="...">1</a></li>     
    <li class="a-normal"><a href="...">2</a></li>   
    <li class="a-last"><a href="...">Next<span class="a-letter-space"></span><span class="a-letter-space"></span>→</a></li>
</ul>
```

In this code, I want to select the second last `li` element. ie. I want to select the `li` that has a `2` in it.

I tried this code

```
WebDriverWait(self.driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//ul[@class='pagination']/li[-2]")))
```

But obviously this does not work. I guess I have to change the `-2` to something. not sure how to do that though. How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `last()` feature of xpath.

```
WebDriverWait(self.driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//ul[@class='pagination']/li[last()-1]")))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach will be
using xpath with contains function as you want to select the list item which contains 2 in it.

```
//ul/li[contains(text(),'2')]
```

You can also mention the class name of ul if your page contains more unordered lists.

```
//ul[@class='pagination']/li[contains(text(),'2')]
```